# Mongoose - find matching array values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, api, mongoose

I'm creating a REST API with Node.js using Mongoose to access my backend MongoDB database. I have an array (variations) inside of one of my collections (also variations) and need to retrieve the object in the array that matches a provided value.

So far I've got this which returns an empty value...

```
//Get variation by ID
app.get('/v1/:id', async (request, response) => {
    try {
        var result = await variationsModel.find({ 'variationID': request.params.id }).exec();
        response.send(result);
    } catch (error) {
        response.status(500).send(error);
    }
})
```

And here's the model I've defined in the API...

```
const variationsModel = mongoose.model("variations", {
    "variations": [
        {
        "variationID": String,
        "custID": String,
        "projID": String,
        "variationTitle": String,
        "variationDesc": String,
        "variationStatus": String,
        "variationChargeable": String,
        "variationCost": String,
        "requireMaterial": String,
        "variationRequestor": String,
        "variationCreationDate": String,
        "variationImages": [
            {
            "imageId": String
            }
        ],
        "variationCategory": String
        }
    ]
});
```

Anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should be

```
variationsModel.find({ 'variations.variationID': request.params.id }).exec();
```

Comment: Course it is! Thanks for your help!